# Hibernate entity join with column restriction

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Say that I have these two entities:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private Collection<B> bCollection;
    ...
}

@Entity
class B {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "aId")
    private A a;

    private boolean restricted;
    ...
}
```

My question is: what can I do to fetch only B entities with `restricted = false` in A.bCollection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hibernate filters:

```
@Filter(
        name = "restrictedFilter",
        condition="restricted = TRUE"
    )
```

See this for more info http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/

**EDIT**: I've just come across a much simpler solution than using Filters. use a @Where annotation:

```
@Where(clause="restricted = TRUE")
private Collection<B> bCollection;
```